# Not seeing anything in arduino serial monitor when typing the AT Commands for Bluetooth HC-05

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, hc-05

I am a beginner to arduino and trying to follow one of the videos from youtube to make a project- Master And Slave using HC-05 modules. I followed every step from that video carefully. Here's the link to the video -> 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXXAcFOTnBo
For Slave Module when I type AT commands in the serial monitor nothing shows up.
I searched in Internet for the this problem and still didn't fix it. Here's What i have done:

1. tired restarting my pc
2. tried Changing arduino, At first i used arduino nano and then uno
3. I tried changing the baud rate to all other values and nothing happened

And there is no change in light blink, it stays on AT command mode until power is turned off and on again.

[This is how is looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q62x.jpg)

Thank You For the Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not actually related to arduino in any way. This tutorial is utilizing onboard USB->UART transceiver IC. So in theory you could even remove Atmel chip from the board. Its more like using module like this [FT232 converter](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/FTDI-FT232RL-USB-to-TTL-Serial-Converter-Adapter-Module-5V-and-3-3V-Cable/222536957569?epid=21023600160&hash=item33d03c7e81:g:XNoAAOSwGJlZNsiJ:rk:2:pf:0). Anyways sorry if I confused you but you can research the subject.

But anyways to the problem. Couple of questions:

1. Did you press reset button on module while powerin up the circuit?

   - Thats the way it enters to AT command mode
2. Did you try to reverse RX-TX lines, don't worry connecting these guys across eatch other doesn't harm your board.
   (They are so often plugged in wrong..)
3. Did you make sure you have connected EN pin of module also. (To arduino 3.3V not 5V)
4. Did you triple check all connections
5. Try to upload simple Sketch like blinky to Arduino to make sure you are connected to USB-UART transeiver and you have correct drivers.
6. Make sure you upload empty sketch or remove the chip when you try to apply tutorial steps.
7. Change jumper wires. Sometimes cheap jumper wires are really bad quality. 
   I have been sometimes scratching head for long time because of broken jumper cable.

Please let me know if you have checked all of those so we can think for next step.

Comment: Also did you actually press send after writing at to the terminal